# How to interpret --audit and --invert_hash output for vowpal wabbit --rank model?

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

I'm using the VW windows binary (v8.1.1), and I cannot find/run the gd_mf_weights file to produce the latent factors from matrix factorization models on the movielens data. Is it possible to retrieve the latent item/user vectors with the --audit or --invert_hash command for the --rank model? How do I interpret the output?

--audit

```
0.083820 0
user^0:40152322256(250064):1:0.0203829  item^0:39109980128(2289632):1:0.034971
5 1
5 2
5 3
5 4
5 5
2.255293 6
```

--invert_hash

```
options: --quadratic ui --rank 5
Checksum: -1594367130
0 0.026660 0.029663 0.066095 0.001638 0.024027 0.049405 0.086664 0.039567 0.004046 0.004133 0.001141
1 0.071812 0.048789 0.009294 0.078689 0.055306 0.079207 0.051241 0.033831 0.038871 0.034245 0.004538
2 0.068148 0.066196 0.043153 0.090472 0.039405 0.068468 0.028950 0.047775 0.065153 0.068769 0.089713
3 0.061660 0.051192 0.036081 0.077850 0.084801 0.042123 0.092750 0.059213 0.045027 0.071334 0.062931
4 0.087708 0.096122 0.003722 0.065780 0.036524 0.008498 0.071953 0.025418 0.038625 0.085860 0.069624
5 0.048324 0.097188 0.020505 0.055188 0.065675 0.010707 0.099586 0.061309 0.013237 0.007674 0.021914
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for using `-q` with `--rank` instead of the built-in low-rank quadratic interaction `--lrq`?

Here's how I would train a factorization machine recommender with `--lrq` and `--invert_hash`. Let's say your dataset looks like:

```
4 |u john |i hammer
...
```

Which encodes the information that user "john" gave item "hammer" a rating of 4 etc.

I would train the model as follows:

```
$ echo "4 |u john |i hammer" | vw --lrq ui5 --invert_hash model.readable.txt
```

And then extract the latent factors from `model.readable.txt` (everything below the "`:0`" line):

```
$ cat model.readable.txt
Version 8.6.1
Id 
Min label:0
Max label:4
bits:18
lda:0
0 ngram:
0 skip:
options: --hash_seed 0 --link identity --lrq ui5
Checksum: 3876651432
:0
Constant:142048:0.231715
i^hammer:99576:0.231715
lrq^i^hammer^1:99577:0.238051
lrq^i^hammer^2:99578:0.641153
lrq^i^hammer^3:99579:0.177484
lrq^i^hammer^4:99580:0.333955
lrq^i^hammer^5:99581:2.82811
lrq^u^john^1:15281:1.23084
lrq^u^john^2:15282:0.457055
lrq^u^john^3:15283:1.65113
lrq^u^john^4:15284:0.877392
lrq^u^john^5:15285:0.103614
u^john:15280:0.231715
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'm evaluating matrix factorization results between --rank and --lrq methods in VW and was able to interpret the --lrq output but not the --rank output. I still have problems generating weights from a trained --rank model even using gd_mf_weights and posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046656/vowpal-wabbit-cannot-retrieve-latent-factors-with-gd-mf-weights-from-a-trained .

Comment: I see. I think I've actually done this in the past, before I knew about `--lrq`. I believe my approach was to create a minimal dataset to do a linear pass over all tokens and then use `--audit` to parse the learned weights. This is implemented in [here](https://github.com/KristianHolsheimer/vw_glove/blob/master/glove.py#L366).